# How to generate list of my relevant publications for each chapter from bibliography that may or may not have been cited already

Tags: bibliographies

I have a single **reference.bib** file housing all my research publications and other citations(around 200 entries). My goal is to print only my chapter-specific publications at the end of each chapter, mirroring the format used in the bibliography section, but with heading **Related publications**. Is it feasible to utilize the shared **reference.bib** file and selectively include the desired entries in this manner? The entries may not be present as citation in that chapter already (Our university does not allow self citation). Sorry, could not provide any useful MWE as I do not have any idea where to start for this case. Please consider that the entries of my publications are in reference.bib but not cited in the chapter.

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc,a4paper,11pt,oneside,chapterprefix=true,sfdefaults=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
\begin{document}
\include{chapter1} % Include the first chapter file.
\include{chapter2} % Include the second chapter file.
% Include other chapters as needed.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```